# Set object origin and transform to face midpoint AND normal via Python

Tags: python, normals, origin

The answer to the above question seems to involve moving the scene cursor to the selected face, performing some matrix magic (math) and at one point using `bpy.ops.object.origin_set` without ruining said matrix magic.

Any chance that anyone has done this before, or know the actual math required for it?

NOTE: My objects are not at the origin and may be rotated already!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140605/setting-meshs-origin-in-python-2-8   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/changing-object-origin-to-arbitrary-point-without-origin-set   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183552/how-to-have-an-object-lie-on-a-specific-face/183724#183724   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177889/calculating-and-exporting-global-rotation-of-faces-created-from-splitting-an-iso/177913#177913

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm also looking at this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209798/38603

Comment: Would you say it's a Possible duplicate?

Comment: If I can get some of the answers to work, but so far, I can't get the math to work out. For example, the link I pasted only works if the object is at the origin, which mine are not (so I added an edit to clarify that in the question above).

Comment: NOTE. re bumps  and [in regard  to comments here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177889/calculating-and-exporting-global-rotation-of-faces-created-from-splitting-an-iso/177913#comment361835_177913)  it is a simple process to move an object to origin by multiplying by its matrix world inverted. Apply any code that works at origin while object is there, then transform back.  Still think this has been well covered AND IMO is if not a dupe, a combination of two dupes.  Please consider editing the **specifics** of what you are having difficulty with  into question.